# Center border and position of picture

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my border and picture with laptop. I would like to grey and white border be in place. If i reduce resolution - border not stay on position. Image have the same problem.

This is my first project. Please give me some advice about my code.

https://szymal.github.io/hello-minimal/index.html

Comment: About what image are you talking on the website?

Comment: Laptop image with glass of water

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you push all columns with % margins and not put them into a centered container? Then the 2 navigations can be inside a left-floating container and the image can float to the right and no need to use position: absolute. With your current HTML just some hacks would be possible that will not be a good solution.

Comment: This is my first project and maybe this is reason. Okej i change this. How change white and grey border ?

Comment: The only border that I see is part of the image itself

Comment: White and grey belt at offer about and contact

Comment: The main problem is that those to color belts have a percentage based `margin-top`. Change that to a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into bootstrap. More specifically

`.img-responsive` -> Makes an image responsive (will scale nicely to the parent element)

You can find more details here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

Once you look into that you can start looking into rows and columns with bootstrap as well. It makes everything easier in my opinion.

As for the for the border issue:

```
border-top: 1px solid white;

border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
```

I hope this helps!